# how to terminate pynput keyboard listener with a timer or a pressed key?

Tags: python, pynput

I know how to terminate pynput keyboard listener with a timer or with a specific key to be pressed (they are both discussed here in this forum).
I cannot find a way to mix the 2 so that the listener is terminated after a preset amount of time or before that time if a specific key (Key.end for example is pressed)
I tried many combinations but none of them work so far.
added after @martineau comments:

an apparently natural way to do it could be:

```
from pynput import keyboard as kb
from time import time
exit_script=False
def action_press(key):
    global exit_script
    if key == kb.Key.end:
        print ('end pressed')
        exit_script= True
    return False
timeOn=10
t0=time()
with  kb.Listener(on_press=action_press,suppress=True) as l:
    while exit_script== False and time()-t0<timeOn:
        pass
    l.join()
print('listener terminated')
```

But it fails to terminate with the timer criteria.

Does somebody know how correct this or if there is an alternative approach??
Thks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found one answer using pynput controller. It does the trick.

```
from pynput import keyboard as kb
from time import time
mykb=kb.Controller()
exit_script=False
def action_press(key):
    global exit_script
    if key == kb.Key.end:
        print ('end pressed')
        exit_script= True
    return False
timeOn=10
t0=time()
with  kb.Listener(on_press=action_press,suppress=True) as l:
    while exit_script== False:
        if time()-t0>timeOn:
            mykb.press(kb.Key.end)
            mykb.release(kb.Key.end)
        

      
    l.join()
print('listener termianted')
```